# How to print lines containing a certain number, but not containing other numbers that never previously appeared?

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a file containing many numbers, written with 10 leading digits and with "A" temporarily placed before and "Z" placed after, to make sure scripts do not misidentify the beginning and ending of a number. E.g.:

```
A00000000001Z
A00000000003Z,A00000000004Z;A00000000005Z
A00000000004Z A00000000005Zsome wordsA00000000001Z
A00000000006Z;A00000000005Z
A00000000001Z
```

I need to search for a particular number, but output only those lines where the number is found, but no other numbers that never previously appeared are on the same line.

For example, if I searched for "0000000001", it would print lines 1, 3, and 5:

```
A00000000001Z
A00000000004Z A00000000005Zsome wordsA00000000001Z
A00000000001Z
```

It can print line 3 because the other numbers "00000000004" and "00000000005" previously appeared in line 2.

If I searched for "00000000005", it would print line 3:

```
A00000000004Z A00000000005Zsome wordsA00000000001Z
```

It would not print line 2, because the other numbers "00000000003" and "00000000004" never appeared previously.

So far, I have worked out this:

```
# search for the line and print the previously appearing lines to a temporary file
grep -B 10000000 0000000001 file.txt > output.temp

# send the last line to another file
cat output.temp | tail -1 > output.temp1
sed -i '$ d' output.tmp > output.temp2

# search for numbers appearing in output.temp2
for i in 1 .. 1000000 NOT original number
     a=`printf $010d $i`
     if [ $a FOUND in output.temp2]
     then
          # check if was found in the previous line
          if [ $a NOT FOUND in output.temp1]
          else

          fi    
     fi
done < ./file.txt
```

How can I print out only those lines containing a certain number, while excluding the other numbers that never previously appeared in the file?

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing your requirement, the double negative in "no other numbers that never previously appeared" is confusing.

Comment: Show us the real data file and write why you like to have this type of solution.  It may help us to understand your problem and solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly bash, but here it is in Python2 that you can run from the shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import sys

def find_valid_ids(input_file, target_id):
    with open(input_file) as f:
        found_ids = set()
        for line in f.readlines():
            ids = set(re.findall(r'A\d+Z', line))
            if (target_id in ids and
                (len(ids - found_ids) == 0 or
                 (len(ids) == 1 and target_id in ids))):
                print line.strip('\n')
            found_ids |= ids

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        find_valid_ids(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
    except IndexError as e:
        print 'Usage: ./find_valid_ids.py input_file target_id'
```

So if you saved the above as `find_valid_ids.py` you'd `$ chmod +x find_valid_ids.py` and run it like `$ ./find_valid_ids.py your_input_file.txt A00000000001Z`